# Showing Parallelism is an equivalence relation in $\Bbb R ^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $L$ denote the set of all lines in the Euclidean plane $\Bbb R^2$. We say that two lines $L$ and $M$ are parallel if either $L = M$ or $L$ and $M$ have no points in common.

Using Euclid’s Parallel Postulate prove that parallelism is an equivalence relation on the set $L$.

I need some help determining if I have the right idea about this.

$L=L$ which means that $L$ is parallel to itself. So this is reflexive.

Suppose we have $L || M$. Then Either $L=M$ or $L$ and $M$ share no points. So Then $M=L$ or $M$ and $L$ share no points. Then $M||L$. So this is symmetric.

Suppose we have $L || M$ and $M || N$. So then either $L=M$ or $L$ and $M$ share no points and either $M=N$ or $M$ and $N$ share no points. So we have that either $L=N$ or $L$ and $N$ share no points. So $L || N$. So then this is transitive.

So from all of this, parallelism is an equivalence relation. I'm not sure if this is correct or not. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The only non-tautological part is that if $L$ and $M$ share no points and $M$ and $N$ share no pints then $L$ and $N$ don't intersect either. This follows by contradiction from the parallel postulate.